# Able to configure/compile PHP --with-ldap, but LDAP is not listed in phpinfo()

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, php5, php.ini

I am trying to compile PHP with LDAP support using these lines:

```
./configure --prefix=/app/php --with-ldap=/usr     
sudo make     
sudo make install
```

Everything appears to install fine without issue, and PHP runs fine, but when I run a phpinfo, I don't see LDAP listed.

Also, I read somewhere that I could use an ldap.so file in php's ext directory and reference it from php.ini ... ? How does on generate the ldap.so file for php ... ?

Any ideas? I am on Mac OS X 10.5.8, php 5.2.17.

**Update:**

I've used these combinations of flags:

```
--with-ldap
--with-ldap=/usr
--with-ldap=/usr,shared
--with-ldap=shared
```

Of these, "--with-ldap=shared" produces an ldap.so, which when placed into php's ext directory gives this error in Apache:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'ldap.so'  in Unknown on line 0
```

I've Googled this error, but haven't found much to resolve this issue. *Any* help is apprecaited!

Many thanks!

KM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you run `configure` you need to look in config.log to make sure php is correctly finding ldap.

There is nothing to put in `php.ini`. On Linux box with only `--with-ldap` and no `php.ini` phpinfo yields:

```
ldap

LDAP Support => enabled
RCS Version => $Id: ldap.c 293036 2010-01-03 09:23:27Z sebastian $
Total Links => 0/unlimited
API Version => 3001
Vendor Name => OpenLDAP
Vendor Version => 20343
```

Comment: Thanks @embobo. Was able to figure things out. Ended up installing PHP 5.3 from Entropy and making a few other config changes, and my step up looks similar to yours.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile php with ldap it generates the ldap.so file in the ext directory and next thing you have to do is to activate it through php.ini(path to php.ini file found in phpinfo() page)

;extension=php_ldap.so

uncomment this line to enable the ldap module for php

restart apache and start using it..

Comment: I thought as much, but I don't see ldap.so anywhere, let alone in the ext directory. I see ldap.o and ldap.lo, and I tried those in the ext directory, w/ a corresponding php.ini entry to no avail. WDYT?